# PyQt5：How do I trigger a signal in the custom node check box in the QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, checked, qtreewidget

I expect a signal to be triggered when a node is checked, but I can't find one from the official documentation. It doesn't look like QTreeWidget provides this signal for the node's checkbox alone.

[image]

I am using the **itemChanged** signal, but it does not meet my other requirement. The itemChanged signal will trigger **many times** for no reason, but I only expect the signal to trigger **once** when it is checked.

Comment: The `itemChanged` signal is emitted whenever the value of *any* role of *any* item has changed, which could happen for many reasons (and even recursively for 3d/tree models) under certain circumstances. Unfortunately, your question is too vague to provide a valid answer, so please provide a [mre], as a screenshot of the documentation is completely useless.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question, and I need to rethink. Thank you for pointing out my problem.